GDAL zarr dataset GetMetadata() (python) always returns empty
Opening a zarr data file works. I can extract raster data from it. zarr is version 2 and and the attributs are consolidated (.zmetadata). GetMetadata() always returns emtpy. I am using gdal version 3.8.5 with python 3.11.8

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Maybe most of the contents of the .zmetadata file is not metadata as it is understood in the GDAL raster datamodel https://gdal.org/user/raster_data_model.html#dataset. Maybe the Python autotest at https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gdrivers/zarr_driver.py#L885 can help understanding how consolidated metadata are interpreted.
